Query Optimization and Removal of Sub Queries
I am having performance related issues regarding this query used for a report.  The report is going after a view 'dbo.v_auto_no_home' This view has a join on landing_CIM_NIN_DOB. The landing_CIM_NIN_DOB table has 40 million records. I added an index to the table and it greatly improved the speed.  I am still wondering if its possible to remove the subqueries and/or any other areas for improvement query wise.  This is SQL Server 2019 RTM.
select
        vautonohom0_.membership_id as col_0_0_,
        vautonohom0_.membership_name as col_1_0_,
        max(vautonohom0_.coverage_age) as col_2_0_,
        min(vautonohom0_.coverage_age) as col_3_0_,
        vautonohom0_.renewal_month as col_4_0_,
        max(vautonohom0_.policy_deposit_premium) as col_5_0_,
        vautonohom0_.life_insured_amount as col_6_0_,
        vautonohom0_.zip_postal_code as col_7_0_,
        (select
            membership1_.membership_agent_assignment_id 
        from
            membership_agent_assignment membership1_ 
        where
            membership1_.membership_id=vautonohom0_.membership_id 
            and membership1_.record_expiration_date>current_timestamp 
            and (
                membership1_.assignment_type='ASSIGNMENT' 
                or membership1_.assignment_type='NO_CALL_FLAG' 
                and membership1_.agent_email_address='johndoe@gmail.com'
            )) as col_8_0_ 
    from
        v_auto_no_home vautonohom0_ 
    where
        (
            vautonohom0_.membership_id in (
                select
                    dimcustome4_.membership_id 
                from
                    fact_policy_coverage factpolicy2_ 
                inner join
                    v_impersonated_agent dimagent3_ 
                        on factpolicy2_.dim_agent_id=dimagent3_.dim_agent_id 
                inner join
                    dim_customer dimcustome4_ 
                        on factpolicy2_.dim_customer_id=dimcustome4_.dim_customer_id 
                where
                    dimagent3_.agent_number in (
                        '0108132'
                    ) 
                group by
                    dimcustome4_.membership_id
            )
        ) 
        and (
            '' in (
                'September'
            ) 
            or vautonohom0_.renewal_month in (
                'September'
            )
        ) 
        and (
            0=0 
            or vautonohom0_.membership_id not in  (
                select
                    membership5_.membership_id 
                from
                    membership_agent_assignment membership5_ 
                where
                    membership5_.membership_id=vautonohom0_.membership_id 
                    and membership5_.record_expiration_date>current_timestamp 
                    and membership5_.assignment_type='NO_CALL_FLAG' 
                    and membership5_.agent_email_address='johndoe@gmail.com'
            )
        ) 
    group by
        vautonohom0_.membership_id ,
        vautonohom0_.membership_name ,
        vautonohom0_.life_insured_amount ,
        vautonohom0_.zip_postal_code ,
        vautonohom0_.renewal_month 
    order by
        vautonohom0_.membership_id desc


For performance questions you need to provide table definitions and query plans

Here is the optimized version of the SQL query from https://www.javainuse.com/opt:
SELECT 
        vautonohom0_.membership_id,
        vautonohom0_.membership_name,
        MAX(vautonohom0_.coverage_age) AS coverage_age,
        MIN(vautonohom0_.coverage_age) AS lowest_coverage_age,
        vautonohom0_.renewal_month,
        MAX(vautonohom0_.policy_deposit_premium) AS max_policy_deposit,
        vautonohom0_.life_insured_amount,
        vautonohom0_.zip_postal_code,
        CASE WHEN 
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM membership_agent_assignment membership1_
                WHERE membership1_.membership_id = vautonohom0_.membership_id
                    AND membership1_.record_expiration_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                    AND (
                        membership1_.assignment_type = 'ASSIGNMENT' 
                        OR membership1_.assignment_type = 'NO_CALL_FLAG' 
                        AND membership1_.agent_email_address = 'johndoe@gmail.com'
                    )
            ) THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END AS has_johndoe_assignment,
    FROM 
        v_auto_no_home vautonohom0_
 WHERE 
        vautonohom0_.membership_id IN (
            SELECT 
                dimcustome4_.membership_id
            FROM 
                fact_policy_coverage factpolicy2_
            INNER JOIN 
                v_impersonated_agent dimagent3_
                ON factpolicy2_.dim_agent_id = dimagent3_.dim_agent_id
            INNER JOIN 
                dim_customer dimcustome4_
                ON factpolicy2_.dim_customer_id = dimcustome4_.dim_customer_id
            WHERE 
                dimagent3_.agent_number = '0108132'
            GROUP BY 
                dimcustome4_.membership_id
        ) 
        AND (
            'September' IN ('', vautonohom0_.renewal_month) 
        ) 
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM membership_agent_assignment membership5_
            WHERE membership5_.membership_id = vautonohom0_.membership_id
                AND membership5_.record_expiration_date


Providing a script-generated "optimization", without being provided an execution plan, indexes, etc. from the OP, wouldn't be a quality answer.

In general, SQL's optimizer will rewrite many of the various different syntax patterns such that you don't need to consider rule-based optimizer patterns from years ago.  Without the schema, indexes, and plans, I agree with @HardCode that there is no validity in looking at some random syntactic rewrite for SQL Server queries.
